# Jquery fade elements one by one and remove last element if limit is exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, limit, fadein

**Question 1:**
I want to fade each href or img tag as they are loaded with delay, so it looks as if they are loaded separately.  I dont know which to use, `delay()` , `fadeToggle()`  or `fadeIn()` `

At moment i get all of them using the code below, which will display in one go, every 20 second. any duplicate images are not shown as they would already be loaded in the array.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var existingElements= new Array(); // array of existing images

        setInterval(function(){
            $.get("/helloworld", function(data){
                data = $.parseJSON(data);

                for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    if($.inArray(data[i]["id"], existingElements) == -1){



                       var imagelinks = '<a class="removethis" href="link">'
                       +'<img src="'+data[i]["img"]+'"/>   </a>';

                       $(imagelinks).prependTo("#somediv").delay(300);


                       existingElements.push(data[i]["id"]);


                        }

 /// add limit here, see below
                    }
                });
            }, 20000);
        });
```

**Question 2:**
The div `somediv` can only have at max of 20 images. so if more than 20(exceed) images are brought in by json. i want to remove that last set images, since the above code will always bring in new images after 20 seconds, should i set a limit as follow:

```
 if(i > 20){
$("#somediv .removethis:last").fadeOut(); // should i use remove()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
var existingElements = {};
var somediv = $("#somediv");

(function loopy() {
    $.get("/helloworld", function(data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var imagelinks = [];
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (!existingElements[data[i]["id"]]) {
                imagelinks.push('<a class="removethis" href="link">' + '<img src="' + data[i]["img"] + '"/></a>');
                existingElements[data[i]["id"]] = data;
            }
        }
        // Add then all to the dom at once, hide them
        //then find that last one and start fading in.
        $(imagelinks.join('')).prependTo(somediv).hide().filter(":last").fadeIn("slow", fadeNext);
        setTimeout(loopy, 20000);
    });
})();

function fadeNext() {
    // Fade the next image in
    $(this).prev().fadeIn(fadeNext);
    //If there are more than 20 images visible fade the others out
    var more = somediv.find("img:visible:not(:animated):gt(20)");
    if (more.length) {
        more.fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you sir are a genius. although somediv variable was replaced with `$("#somediv")` to get it work, anyway thanks